# Replicated Site Variables, hopefully this is not too custom

Tags: dhtml

I just got involved in some bug fixes on a custom project and here are some of the replicated site variables. The site appears to me mostly `dhtml`.

```
~repname~

Name that distributor chooses to display.
~repemail~

Email that distributor chooses to display.
~repphone~

Phone number that distributor chooses to display.

~repgif~

A picture the distributor chooses to display.
~repgif1~
```

Here's the only write up I have for these site variables.

To remove special characters from the rep fields on the replicated sites so that they can be used in javascript and flash files, include in the variable ":clear"
In other words it removes "&", "<", ">" from the text so that m&ms would display as mms.
Example: The variables would look like this:
~repname:clear~ and ~repemail:clear~

My question is how to use a variable like repgif? What does the tilde mean? I guess this is all just the original programmers shortcode, right?

I've tried using

```
<img src='repgif'>
<img src='~repgif'>
~repgif~
~repgif:clear~
```

If anyone has any ideas or can help it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.